# Why std:: is not needed when using ispunct() in C++?

Tags: c++, std

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using std::string;
using std::cin;
using std::cout; using std::endl;

int main()
{
    string s("Hello World!!!");
    decltype(s.size()) punct_cnt = 0;
    for (auto c : s)
        if (ispunct(c))
            ++punct_cnt;
    cout << punct_cnt
         << " punctuation characters in " << s << endl;
}
```

It seems that I can use `ispunct()` without `std::` or declaring `using std::ispunct;` but I can't do that with `std::cout` or `std::cin`. Why is this happening?

Comment: All of C was grandfathered into the global namespace, so C code would compile as-is.

Comment: You should say `size_t` instead of `decltype(s.size())`.

Comment: @Mehrdad why? It's a bit verbose perhaps, but I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: @jalf: To help readers of the code to more easily understand it.

Comment: @jalf: Because this coding convention unnecessarily duplicates code -- once to specify the type, once the value. (It isn't happening here, but it ends up happening most of the time.) Also celtschk's reason.

Comment: @Mehrdad I don't follow, what does it duplicate? It expresses very precisely that the type of the value should be the same as is used for the string's size function's return value. It is not actually equivalent to `size_t`, but to `std::string::size_type` (which is typically, but not *guaranteed to be*, the same type) It is an unconventional way to express this, but I see no unnecessary duplication.

Comment: @jalf: **It is 100% illegal** for `std::string::size_type` to be anything other than `size_t`, since `std::basic_string<char_type>::size_type` is defined to be `std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<char_type>>::size_type` which is defined to be `std::allocator<char_type>::size_type` which is defined to be **`size_t`**.

Comment: @jalf: Regarding the duplication, I was saying that that this **coding convention** (i.e. using `decltype` rather than `auto` or the actual type) often results in code duplication, so it's best not to get into the habit of using it unless it's actually necessary.

Comment: @Mehrdad I was not aware of that regarding `size_type`. But we agree then that there is no duplication *in this case*? I agree, of course, stuff like `decltype(2+2) x = 2+2;` obviously duplicates code, and if you consistently use `decltype in that manner, it'd be silly (and could just be replaced by `auto` Critiquing the code for duplication which *isn't actually there* seems odd though.

Comment: @jalf: We agree there isn't a duplication *in this case*, but I don't consider that to be making the situation any better. It's like claiming `decltype(v.begin()) i = v.end();` doesn't duplicate any code... well, no, it doesn't "duplicate" anything in the copy-paste sense, but if you go around reasoning about things like this then you're just fooling yourself; it's code duplication in my eyes.

Comment: How are you "fooling yourself"? On the contrary, this is remarkably explicit and precise code, saying "I want this type to be suitable for storing numbers corresponding to the size of a `std::string`. Which is precisely what it is *used* for. Once again, it is an odd and cumbersome way to write the code, but I see no "duplication", and I see no "fooling" anyone. You haven't really made the case for *why* this is bad.

Comment: @Mehrdad I don't see a requirement anywhere for `std::allocator::size_type` to be `size_t`. § 17.6.3.5 Table 28 of the standard for Allocator requirements lists `X::size_type` to be an "unsigned integer type", not explicitly `size_t`.

Comment: @Rapptz: That's because not every allocator is `std::allocator`. But the allocator for `std::basic_string<char_type>::allocator_type` is `std::allocator<char_type>`, which has this requirement.

Comment: @Mehrdad I don't know what specialisation you're talking about for `std::allocator<char_type>`, but the only specialisations required by the standard is `std::allocator<void>`. So `std::allocator<char_type>` to the best of my knowledge follows the general requirements listed in Table 28 of the standard.

Comment: *Anyway*, I still don't think `decltype(s.size())` is bad code. If it was any other string with a specialised allocator or whatever then it'll return whatever type is specified there since we're being pedantic.

Comment: @Rapptz: I'm referring to [20.8.9 of the latest draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf) on page 531 which explicitly says `typedef size_t size_type;` inside `template <class T> class allocator`. The string isn't specialized with any nonstandard type here so `size_type` wouldn't help anything no matter how pedantic you try to be. :)

Comment: @jthill interestingly, it is quite easy for C code to not compile as is even with the global namespace pollution (something as simple as `int* x = malloc(sizeof(int));` will fail).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It means `ispunct` is part of the global namespace, rather than the `std` namespace. This is probably because `ispunct` is one of the functions brought over from C (hence it is in `cctype`).

On the other hand, `cout` and `cin` are part of the `std` namespace, not the global namespace.

### Edit:

As to *why* things from C are in the global namespace instead of in the `std` namespace, I believe it has to do with allowing C code to compile by a C++ compiler with minimal changes, since [C++ aims to be compatible with C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B).

According to the comments, `ispunct` is **allowed**, but not **required**, to be in the global namespace (but is **required** to be in the `std` namespace), in `<cctype>`. However, if you had included `<ctype.h>` instead, `ispunct` would be **required** to be in the global namespace.

Comment: `<cctype>` is required to put `ispunct` into `std` and is allowed to also put it in the global namespace.

Comment: The compatibility rule is fulfilled by providing the `xxx.h` headers, which have the exact same name as the corresponding C header and make their names available in the global namespace. Since a C program would never include the `cxxx` version (for the simple reason that it doesn't exist in the C standard), C compatibility cannot be a reason for the `cxxx` headers defining the names in the global namespace.

Comment: @PeteBecker By 'allowed', do you mean that some implementations might not put functions such as `ispunct` in the global namespace?

Comment: @maditya - they are **allowed** to but not **required** to. To put the names in the global namespace use the C headers.

Comment: @PeteBecker Ah, ok. Together with celtschk's comments, this suggests that most library implementers simply `#include <ctype.h>` in their `cctype` headers.

Answer (score 4):

C names (those you get from including a `xxx.h` header from C) are allowed to be in the global namespace in addition to the `::std` namespace even if you are including the `cxxx` version of the header. This has been done because it can be a problem not to have those in the global namespace if you provide the C++ implementation, but not the C implementation (so the actual C headers are from a compiler you don't control).

In your case, `ispunct` comes from the header `ctype.h`. While you are including the `cctype` header, this in turn includes the `ctype.h` header which declares the symbol `ispunct` in the global namespace.

Comment: You say they "are allowed to" be in the global namespace. Does this mean that the given code example could fail to compile in another compiler? Or is `ispunct` actually *guaranteed* to be in the global namespace if you `#include <cctype>`?

Comment: They're actually **guaranteed** to be in the global namespace. §17.6.1.2.4 of N3337 (C++11): "the contents of each header `*c*name` shall be the same as that of the corresponding header `name.h`, **as specified in the C standard library or the C Unicode
TR, as appropriate, as if by inclusion**. In the C++ standard library, however, the declarations [...] are within namespace scope of the namespace std. It is unspecified whether these names are first declared within the global namespace scope and are then injected into namespace std by explicit using-declarations" (emph. mine)

Comment: @peppe: Thank you. I was searching for information about it, but couldn't find it. I always thought it was optional, given that originally the `cxxx` headers were *forbidden* to have the names in the global scope; which was revised because of the difficulties with that. I would have thought that implementations implementing the previous rules would not be rendered non-conforming (but then, maybe the revision was already before C++98 was published, or alternatively no compiler actually implemented the specification anyway). I'll fix the answer.

Comment: @peppe: I've now rolled back to my original version due to Pete Becker's answer and his reply to my comment there.

Comment: @peppe - the second rule of statutory construction is "read on". The sentence that follows the one you quoted says "In the C++ standard library, however, the declarations (except for names which are defined as macros in C) are within namespace scope (3.3.6) of the namespace std." There was never any intention to require the `c*` headers to also put names into the global namespace. In fact, the initial requirement was just the opposite: they could **not** put names into the global namespace. This was essentially unimplementable for some vendors, so the rule was weakened to **allow** it.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I actually pasted that part -- but I assumed that it didn't refer to the C-like header contents (as it says that the C-like headers are treated "as by inclusion", and therefore would put everything in the global namespace). But I guess you're right...

Comment: @peppe  - whoops, I see it now; the boldface distracted me.

Answer (score 2):

C++ headers derived from C (such as `<cctype>`) are required to put the names of things that they declare in the namespace `std` and they are **permitted** to also put them in the global namespace. Formally, this wasn't allowed until C++11, but the old rule that those headers were not allowed to put names into the global namespace could not be implemented reasonably and was commonly ignored.

Comment: So my answer *before* changing it due to peppe's comment was correct?

Comment: @peppe left out the sentence that follows the quoted text: "In the C++ standard library, however, the declarations (except for names which are defined as macros in C) are within namespace scope (3.3.6) of the namespace std." And, for completeness, the sentence after that is: "It is unspecified whether these names are first declared within the global namespace scope and are then injected into namespace std by explicit using-declarations (7.3.3)."