# passing std::ispunct as argument to remove_copy_if() fails to compile

Tags: c++, namespaces

I tried to pass `std::ispunct` as the last argument to `remove_copy_if`, and found it failed to compile.
However, if I pass `ispunct` (just with `std::` removed), the program compiles and runs as expected.

code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<cctype>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iterator>

using std::map;
using std::string;

string strip_punct(const string &s) {
    string target;
    remove_copy_if(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(target), std::ispunct);
    return target;
}

int main() {
    string word = "abc.";
    string target = strip_punct(word);
    std::cout << "target: " << target << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

error message:

```
$ g++ --std=c++11 -o problem_11_4.out problem_11_4.cpp
problem_11_4.cpp: In function 'std::string strip_punct(const string&)':
problem_11_4.cpp:12:80: error: no matching function for call to 'remove_copy_if(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::const_iterator, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::const_iterator, std::back_insert_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
   12 |     remove_copy_if(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(target), std::ispunct);
      |                                                                                ^
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.2.0_1/include/c++/9.2.0/algorithm:62,
                 from problem_11_4.cpp:4:
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.2.0_1/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_algo.h:703:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _IIter, class _OIter, class _Predicate> _OIter std::remove_copy_if(_IIter, _IIter, _OIter, _Predicate)'
  703 |     remove_copy_if(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.2.0_1/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_algo.h:703:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
problem_11_4.cpp:12:80: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter '_Predicate'
   12 |     remove_copy_if(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(target), std::ispunct);
      |                                                                                ^
```

I searched on SO and found this question: [Why std:: is not needed when using ispunct() in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18047031/why-std-is-not-needed-when-using-ispunct-in-c)
It is helpful, now I know `ispunct` can be used without `std::`. However, I wrote another program and found out that `ispunct` and `std::ispunct` both work well when used alone (not as an argument). I still don't understand why `std::` is not allowed when `ispunct` is used as an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::ispunct` is an overloaded function.  There exists a version in [`<cctype>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/ispunct) and a version in [`<locale>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ispunct).  Even though you don't include `<locale>`, one of your includes does which brings in the overload and leads to the deduction failing since overloaded functions can't have a type deduced.

What you can do to solve this is to wrap `std::ispunct` in a lambda since in the body of the lambda the compiler can preform overload resolution and call the correct function.  That would give you

```
remove_copy_if(s.begin(), 
               s.end(), 
               std::back_inserter(target), 
               [](unsigned char ch){ return std::ispunct(ch); }); // use unsigned char here to stop any possible UB
```

Comment: Very clear, thanks. And thanks for the information about overloading resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Use a lambda expression instead of the function pointer.

Here is a demonstrative program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

std::string strip_punct( const std::string &s ) 
{
    std::string target;
    std::remove_copy_if( std::begin( s ), std::end( s ), 
                         std::back_inserter( target ), 
                         []( unsigned char c ) { return std::ispunct( c ); } );
    return target;
}

int main() 
{
    std::string word = "abc.";

    std::cout << strip_punct( word ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is there are two `ispunct` functions in C++. One is the C standard `ispunct()` function in the `<ctype.h>` header, and the other is the C++ standard `std::ispunct()` function in the `<locale>` header.