# when should we use std:: in c++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    char a[]="abc";
    char b[]="def";
    std::strcpy(b,a);
    printf("%s\n", b);
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

why `std::` is optional when using printf, while `std::` cannot be omitted with `cout` and `endl`?

In `/usr/include/c++/cstdio`, `printf` is in std namespace.

```
namespace std {
    using ::printf;
}
```

But I do not understand the meaning of `using ::printf`. I only know `using namespace namespace_name`. What does `::` mean? And the using clause is in a namespace, how can it work?

Comment: printf comes from the C standard so you tend to have it both in the global namespace and in the std namespace (this applies to anything from the C standard). so its not that its optional for printf, its that printf is in 'both places'

Comment: See __C compatibility headers__ in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header  _"...and the corresponding cxxx headers are allowed to also declare the same names in the global namespace..."_

Comment: Voted to reopen because the duplicate does not address the question.

Comment: agreed the duplicate is incorrect

Comment: I applied [a new duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18047031/364696); it's not *exact* (it's specifically asking about `ispunct`), but it's the same basic question: "Why are some (unbeknownst to asker) C APIs not required to use `std::` prefixes?" with the same answer.

Comment: The duplicate does answer one part of the question. I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397894/c-using-a-symbol-from-a-namespace) should cover the other part.